# Translation not working in sprinf variable

Tags: multi-language, translation, localization, language

I have a function to get the taxonomy term name like this:

```
function get_term_name($taxo){
$terms = get_terms($taxo);
$html= '';
foreach($terms as $term ) {
   $html .= sprintf( __( '%s', 'twentyfourteen' ), $term->name  ); $html .= '<br>';
   }
   return $html;
}
```

The problem is the return string not translated. What am I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not translated dynamic strings with he translation API, you can translate only static strings that you know in advance.

Comment: I see, is there any workaround?

Comment: no there isn't. How can you translate something that you don't know what it is?